# comparing time in php error

Tags: php, datetime

i'm trying to compare the current time against 5 other times as a schedule but it's not working. Dates are fetched from the database here's the code

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date1 = new DateTime($pRow['date1']);
$date2 = new DateTime($pRow['date2']);
```

dates in database: 
date1: 12:00 
date2: 03:25

```
if($now->format('h:i') >= $date1->format('h:i') && $now->format('h:i') <= $date2->format('h:i')){
echo "date2";   
}
else{
echo "no";  
}
```

the result is always no (code edited to be simple and faster to solve the problem)

Comment: What do all your variables look like? Can you show us the contents by `var_dump()`ing them all?

Comment: Do `var_dump($date1); var_dump($date2);` see what you get and show us the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($now >= $date5 && $now <= $date5)
```

wrong data is comparing

Comment: @ex3v you're absolutely right. Thanks, I've edited post.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `h` modifier for time you are working with only 1-12 for hours. This means 2pm is just 2 and 11am is 11. Therefore 11 > 2 which breaks your math. Use `H` instead.

```
$now = date("H:i",strtotime("now"));
$date1 = date("H:i",strtotime($pRow['date1']));
$date2 = date("H:i",strtotime($pRow['date2']));
$date3 = date("H:i",strtotime($pRow['date3']));
$date4 = date("H:i",strtotime($pRow['date4']));
$date5 = date("H:i",strtotime($pRow['date5']));
```

Or, better yet, use DateTime which are comparable.

```
$now   = new DateTime();
$date1 = new DateTime($pRow['date1']);
$date2 = new DateTime($pRow['date2']);
$date3 = new DateTime($pRow['date3']);
$date4 = new DateTime($pRow['date4']);
$date5 = new DateTime($pRow['date5']);
```

Comment: Ya gotta love it don't ya, when OP's code changes midstream. More than once too.

Comment: Nothing like hitting a moving target.

Comment: DateTime class please. i've copied the code from this page http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php but it tells there's a n error

Comment: @jqbeginner You don't need to get the class. It is built in to PHP.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string - when trying to echo $now

Comment: echo date("h:i",$now) prints error:  Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

Comment: You need to use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) like so `echo $now->format('h:i')`

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($pRow);`

Comment: array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["date1"]=> string(8) "12:00:42" ["date2"]=> string(8) "03:25:42" }

Comment: After seeing that you don't even need DateTime or any date function. You can compare them as strings.

Comment: Hm... has that duck fallen into the pond yet?

Answer (score 0):

This code was already at stackoverflow, try to use it :)

```
$ThatTime ="14:08:10";
if (time() >= strtotime($ThatTime)) {
  echo "The Time that was entered is behind";
}
```